# How to PUSH a new view after receiving some response in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i have an application with **login** and**Applications** pages(not html), i send GET to server and using the response i dynamically create somme buttons which take their properties from the JSON response value. Anything is OK, but even tough i want to create these buttons in a new view they allways come over the login page. Can someone help me to create views which will be loaded after i got the response?
I had asked a question like this but the answers weren't satisfying.. My old question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741037/how-can-i-display-the-result-of-a-method-in-a-new-view)

And finally i did solve my question! Here is what i did

```
myViewController *anObject=[[BNT_1ViewController alloc] init];

                    [self.view addSubview:anObject.view];

                    anObject.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

I placed this into my code and now the buttons go to new page(to anObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UINavigationController. Create a UIViewController and push it using the navigation controller. You will find lots of tutorials regarding UINavigationControllers online

Comment: I did try but couldn't have any result. Since i had explained everything with codes in the other question i just linked it, i created uiviewcontroler and called it just during creating the buttons like this:   
                    UIViewController *myViewController;
                    [myViewController addSubview:buttons];
 but nothing changed..

Comment: Can you please tke a look at the othe question i mention above and give an idea? i want to create buttons in a new view but they come over the login page

Comment: do u know what is a navigation controller? try googling

Comment: I m sorry man i really tried hard but i don't have such a big experience in Objective C, this is why i have so many troubles

Comment: Thats why, go through some tutorials on uinavigationcontroller. Thereafter, you can create a UIviewcontroller, add all you buttons and then you can use the UINavigationController to "push" your new view controller

Comment: I'm not some one who tries to make others do his bussiness but all the tutorial i saw are about table/TableViewControllers..

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488247/how-to-show-a-uinavigationcontroller-with-an-uibutton-on-the-iphone

Comment: Thanks @Shanti, i edited the question about the solvment i did, but i'm not sure if it is the best way..

Answer (score 1):

you need to put if condition. e.g if webservice result is 1 or success push new view/or controller like this.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"AutenticateUserResult"])
{
    recordResult = FALSE;
    greeting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",soapResult];
    NSString *wrongTxt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"1"];
    if( [greeting.text isEqualToString:wrongTxt])
    {
        [myController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
        greeting.text =@"Login success";
    }
    else
    {

       greeting.text=@"Incorrect username or password";
       greeting.hidden=YES; //to hide text to be disply
    }
    [soapResult release];
    soapResult = nil;

    [wrongTxt release];
}
```

**and** 
you can use this to push a view.

```
 [mycontroller pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: i didn't use this code since i was told to change some parts of my project by employers but as i see it is exactly what i had asked. Thanks

Comment: @ilhan 1)take one UINavigation controller 2) on button click event code works perfectly.3) you can also use xml/soap instead of json.